# Is there a shortcut to find the selected object in the outliner?

Tags: shortcut, outliner

I have a scene with a lot of objects which can clutter the outliner very quickly. Is there a shortcut to find the selected object? Basically, if I select an object, I would like to have a shortcut to move my outliner view to include that in the displayed portion of the outliner.

Comment: :O I searched for it using several different keyword combinations!! Oh well, good eye

Comment: "[outliner] numpad" was the search, minus the quotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hover over the outliner view and press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd>. This will move the view to show the object that is selected in the viewport. There is no shortcut if you are hovering over another region.